# Django Template Tag for Previous or Next Month Name

Tags: django, django-templates

I searched through the Django Template Tags Docs and didn't find an easy way to display a date's previous or next month by name.  For example, given a date of Dec 1, 2015, I was hoping to get back the name of the next month 'Jan' as a template tag.

To get back the year, I could do: `{{ selected_date|date:"Y"|add:"-1" }}` to get the previous year.

It seemed fairly common enough that I thought the functionality would be there without having to write a custom tag.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the archive default views that cover date ranges do this by passing in multiple date objects in the context - which is probably what I'd do too. Otherwise, you could write a custom filter to do it - I don't think there's one built in.

Answer (score 1):

The [`MonthArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#montharchiveview) provides `next_month` and `previous_month` in the template context.

However, I think you'll have to create a custom filter to display the next month and previous month for an arbitrary date.

It might be a good idea to add a filter for the next/previous year as well - I think that `{{ selected_date|previous_year }}` is clearer than `{{ selected_date|date:"Y"|add:"-1" }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  Instead of passing in multiple objects in the context, I wrote a quick custom template tag since there wasn't a built-in tag.  Here's how mine looks.

**views.py**

```
#...
return render(request, 'index.html', 
              context={'selected_date': selected_date})  # As @Peter DeGlopper mentioned, alternative could have been to pass in
```

**index.html**

```
{% load template_extras %}

<label>{% get_prev_month_name %}</label>
<label>{% get_next_month_name %}</label>
```

**appname/templatetags/template_extras.py**

```
import datetime

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_next_month_name(context):
    selected_date = context['selected_date']
    next_month = selected_date.month % 12 + 1
    return datetime.date(1900, next_month, 1).strftime("%b")

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_prev_month_name(context):
    selected_date = context['selected_date']
    prev_month = selected_date.month - 1
    if prev_month == 0:
        prev_month = 12
    return datetime.date(1900, prev_month, 1).strftime("%b")

# As @Alasdair mentioned, can create additional tags for say 'previous_year' to make code cleaner
```

Note: Don't forget to restart the server when changing template tags code, add the app to your INSTALLED_APPS variable in `settings.py`, and add `__init__.py` in your templatetags folder (if Python 2).

Comment: If you're going to manually calculate it, I like to do this by adding or subtracting an appropriate `timedelta` rather than handling the wraparound cases with modular arithmetic or if statements. EG, if your `selected_date` is the first of whichever month, add `timedelta(days=31)` to be sure you're in the next month, then `replace(day=1)` to set that date to the first. Or subtract `timedelta(days=1)` to get the last day of the previous month, then `replace` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use python [dateutil.relativedelta](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to calculate the previous or next month based on a given date.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django import template

register = template.Library()


def calculate_date(date, **kwargs):
    """
    Performs date calculation based on an interval.
    Args:
        date (datetime object): The date to which the interval is calculated to.
        **kwargs: Accepts a relative time interval with a positive or negative
            integer to determine if we will add or subtract to the date.
    """
    return date + relativedelta(**kwargs)

@register.assignment_tag
def get_previous_month(selected_date):
    return calculate_date(selected_date, months=-1).strftime("%b")

@register.assignment_tag
def get_next_month(selected_date):
    return calculate_date(selected_date, months=+1).strftime("%b")
```